# How to automate usb_modeswitch?

Tags: networking, usb, udev, usb-modem

I use a USB LTE modem to connect to the internet. The problem is, every time I connect it to my PC, it first gets recognised as a **mass storage device**. I need to manually run this command every time I plug it in: `sudo usb_modeswitch -J -v 12d1 -p 14fe` to change its mode to **Modem/Networkcard**. It's not a great problem, but it becomes very tiring to those steps every time.
How do I automate this process such that every time I plug in the device it gets recognised as a Modem in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules .

For example with a USB LTE stick from another vendor:

```
# own udev rule USB LTE 
# switch from mass storage mode to modem modem
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9bfe", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 1c9e -p 9bfe -M '55534243123456780000000000000606f50402527000000000000000000000'"
# load driver for modem mode
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'modprobe option && echo 1c9e 9b01 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id'"
# rule for modemmanager (example /lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules)
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="mm_longcheer_port_types_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="mm_longcheer_port_types_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", GOTO="mm_longcheer_vendorcheck"
GOTO="mm_longcheer_port_types_end"

LABEL="mm_longcheer_vendorcheck"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="?*", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="03", ENV{ID_MM_LONGCHEER_PORT_TYPE_MODEM}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="00", ENV{ID_MM_LONGCHEER_PORT_TYPE_AUX}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="01", ENV{ID_MM_LONGCHEER_PORT_TYPE_AUX}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", ENV{.MM_USBIFNUM}=="02", ENV{ID_MM_LONGCHEER_PORT_TYPE_AUX}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9b01", ENV{ID_MM_LONGCHEER_TAGGED}="1"

GOTO="mm_longcheer_port_types_end"
```

After saving your rule do `udevadm control --reload-rules`.

see also this longer blog post https://bytefish.de/blog/huawei_e352s5/

Comment: You should point out where your `idVendor` and `idProduct` is specific to your machine and OP needs to replace with their own values. Also how OP can obtain `idVendor` and `idProduct` using `lsusb` or whichever command you used to get your values. Many new users will be unaware of `lsusb` output and correlation to `udev` rules.