# Bluetooth won't turn on after booting windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, windows-10

My bluetooth devices were working fine, until I booted into windows 10. Now the bluetooth dongle in ubuntu 20.04 is detected, but it will not turn on.

lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 Hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your hardware. Can you add this information in your post and als the output oif `lsusb` when everything is fine.

At this part I guess:
Maybe your dongle offers you bluetooth and wifi or bluetooth and mass storage devices. You can use udev, to load the correct driver. See my [asubuntu thread here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247572/how-to-automate-usb-modeswitch/1247602#1247602)